# Returning promise inside function giving typescript type error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I have a scenario where there is a function to check whether userWhiteListing required or not. If not then allowUserToLogin function is called. If yes then check whether specific user is whitelisted or not. If not whitelisted then throw error, else call allowUserToLogin function.

I am looking for a better approach with promise, not with async await.

Here is a sample example for the same.

```
public function sample():Promise<{ session: string , url: string }> {
 return this.userWhiteListingRqd().then((whiteListingRqd) => {    
  if(whiteListingRqd) {
    return this.isUserWhiteListed().then((userWhiteListed) => {
      if(!userWhiteListed) {
        throw new Error("error");
      }
      // Here if user whitelisted then it will go to allowUserToLogin 
      // But here typescript throws error Promise<void> cannot be assignable
      // to Promise<session: string , url:string>
    });
  }  
 });
  return this.allowUserToLogin().then(() => {
     return { session, url }; 
  });
}

private function userWhiteListingRqd(): Promise<boolean> {
  // returns boolean value
}

private isUserWhiteListed(): Promise<boolean> {
  // returns boolean value
}
```

I am still in learning phase. Is there any better approach to handle this scenario using promise.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using async-await in many cases can clean up promise-heavy code.

```js
public async function sample(): Promise<{ session: string; url: string }> {
  if (await this.userWhiteListingRqd() && !(await this.isUserWhiteListed()) {
    throw new Error("The user must be whitelisted but is not.");
  }
  await this.allowUserToLogin();
  return { session, url };
}
```

Comment: Need a solution in promise since I need to align my code with promise...Is there any way you can help me with Promise.

Comment: @Vishnu this does use promises. It just doesn't explicitly use .then() and .catch() because it uses [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) instead.

Comment: Yes correct. But in the code there were many functions which uses promise then catch. So inorder to maintain code properly, i have to use promise then catch.. Can you suggest?

Comment: Just because the rest of the code uses .then() and .catch() doesn't mean all of it has to, you can mix async/await and normal promise methods and it will not hurt readability. That said, I will try to offer you a non-async/await solution

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use async/await, give this a try:

```js
function sample(): Promise<{ session: string; url: string }> {
  return this.userWhiteListingRqd()
    .then((whiteListingRqd) =>
      this.isUserWhitelisted().then(
        (isUserWhitelisted) => isUserWhitelisted || !whiteListingRqd
      )
    )
    .then((userIsAllowed) =>
      userIsAllowed ? this.allowUserToLogin() : Promise.reject(new Error())
    )
    .then(() => ({ session, url }));
}
```

Warning: promise chains like this are not known for being very readable.

Comment: Here in this function, my doubt is this.isUserWhitelisted function will wait for promise to resolve?

Comment: It should wait for this.isUserWhitelisted to resolve.

Comment: sorry i think i missed something. Can you just explain a bit? I didnt get the point if this.isUserWhitelisted is not returning then how it will wait for promise to reolve?

Comment: I assumed you already had a function this.isUserWhitelisted that returned a promise to a boolean. The code then waits for the boolean, makes a new boolean called userIsAllowed, and then takes from there in the next .then statement.